# Using scrollTop to show pixels scrolled

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Im wanting to to display the number of pixels a user has scrolled in my site by using the scrollTop method in jQuery. I would like the number of pixels to appear in a class called 'pixels'.

Therefore I could have

```
<p><span class="pixels"><!--number of pixels here--></span> Pixels Scrolled</p>
```

I found a website that does does it at it's footer. Its exactly what I want to do! You can find the site here http://chartbeat.com/

Although I have been looking and can't seem to find out how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time try a little harder before you ask:

```
$(function(){
  var $w = $(window), display = $(".pixels");

  $w.on("scroll", function(e){
    $display.text($w.scrollTop())
  });
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mb45L/2/

Comment: Why loading jQuery for such a simple matter?

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3 because he taged the question with it. On the other side your answer does only half the work...

Comment: @meo Thank you, I have only started learning jQuery, I'l definitely try harder next time!

Answer (score 1):

It's really as simple as the following:

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined) {
  $(function() {
    var win = $(window),
        ele = $('.pixels');

    win.scroll(function() {
      ele.text(win.scrollTop());
    });
  });
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Comment: `.text()` is a lot faster as `.html()` what is pretty important for an event that is triggered on every scroll...

Comment: Changed to use .text() instead. I wrote it pretty quick, yeah. It could be optimized even further, if we really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop`

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
<p><span class="pixels" style="position:fixed"><!--number of pixels here--></span>     Pixels Scrolled</p>
<?php for($x=0;$x<100;$x++) { echo "<br>"; } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).scroll(function() {
      $(".pixels")[0].innerHTML = $(document).scrollTop();
   });
});

</script>

 </body>
</html>
```